# Data Migration from oracle to db2 in Talend Open Studio

Tags: oracle, db2, data-migration, talend

I have to migrate all the database tables from oracle to db2 in Talend Open Studio tool.
Can anyone please tell me each and every basic steps from starting to end, to migrate the database tables from oracle to db2 in Talend Open Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Every single migration is different, there could be many procedures, however you should adapt them to your environement. Remember that DB2 has many Oracle compatibilities, and IBM continue to increase it. However, you should care about what DB2 version you are using, and what Oracle compatibilities it has. Probably you would like to use the latest version 10.5.

Probably you should use IBM Data Movement Too for the whole process.

You can get a lot of clues to design your migration strategie from the following articles:

- DB2 10: Run Oracle applications on DB2 10 for Linux, UNIX, and Windows - http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0907oracleappsondb2/ This article is written by Serge Rielau, an IBM DB2 expert. There is an overview of the IBM Data Movement Tool.
- DB2 Meet - https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/wikis/home?lang=en#!/wiki/DB2%20for%20LUW%20Application%20Enablement/page/Meet%20DB2 This is a tool that shows you how much do you have to modify your stored procedures in order to be compatible with DB2.
- IBM Data movement tools - http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0906datamovement/

Comment: Both MEET DB2 and IDMT are deprecated, they do not necessarily support DB2 versions newer than 9.7. [IBM Database Conversion Workbench](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/groups/service/html/communityview?communityUuid=05901c97-75b2-47a1-9c32-25f748855913) is the currently available tool.

Comment: Thanks.. Actually I already worked in IBM Data Movement Tool.. It only does flat data migration but I want to perform data cleansing also which is not supported by this tool. So I have searched another open source tool ie. Talend Open Studio which supports data cleansing.. I want to know the basic steps in migrating the database through this tool.